# How to analyse data from different subjects?

Tags: repeated-measures, mean, sas, normalization

DESIGN:
I have 4 laboratory mice (= `4 subjects`). My `factor` is a condition `with 5 levels` (control condition and 4 testing conditions): [gr0], [gr1], [gr2], [gr3], [gr4]. My `response variable` is concentration (measured in pg/mL) of 5 cytokines.

ISSUE:
When we analysed my results we faced a problem of big variation among animals. I was told that it was normal. We did statistical analysis with unpaired t-test for each animal and presented a bar chart with means and SEMs as a "representative experiment". Now my thought is to use all data in my analysis of similar experiments. How? With indices.

CALCULATIONS of relative indices:
My data are in triplicates in general. Some - are duplicates (because of outliers). I do it this way:

1. I calculate arithmetic mean of n-plicates for each of my levels/groups.
2. Then I calculate relative indices: I set the mean for the control group [gr0] as 1 and calculate the others as [gr1]/[gr0], [gr2]/[gr0], [gr3]/[gr0], and [gr4]/[gr0]. Thus, I have 5 indices for the mouse #1.
3. All these calculations I repeat with the data from the rest animals and get a 5 X 5 table with 1's in the control group [gr0].
4. Then I intend to subject this matrix to SAS PROC GLIMMIX...

QUESTIONs:

1. Is it correct to divide an n-plicate mean for a group (i.e. [gr#]/[gr0]) or I should subtract like [gr#] - [gr0]?
2. I suspect that the distribution of the initial raw data is Log-normal. What distribution should I expect with indices? Beta? Binomial?
3. What about SEMs? How to calculate them in case of indices? At step #3? In this case I'll calculate the second mean (the mean based on 5 indices calculated from "raw" means...) and its SE. Right?
4. Is there any logic above?

Thank you.

P.S.
There were two similar but unanswered question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/50898/5003) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/67424/5003).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I follow the logic your proposed analysis. However, your study design sounds like a repeated measures design, with 4 mice, 5 treatments and 20 total observations (pg/mL). I wonder if you can simply analyze using a [repeated measures ANOVA](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/statug_anova_sect014.htm)? Or, if by "a problem of big variation among animals" you mean that the variances violate an assumption required for the repeated measures ANOVA *F* test. If so you might consider [the Friedman test](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/procstat_freq_sect033.htm), which is a nonparametric version of repeated measures ANOVA. The links I provided are to SAS support documentation for these procedures. There are also Wikipedia articles on both:

[Repeated measures ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design)
[Friedman's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test)

Comment: thank you for your answer, you're right about RM design. 20 observations should be multiplied by roughly 3 as my data are triplicates (most of them). The problem is that with t-test I find differences, but can't with ANOVA. Moreover, when I have the final 5X5 table with indices there are only 1s in the control group (after normalisation). So, dispersion of five 1s equals 0 as you well aware. That is I face a problem of violation of ANOVA assumption on homogeneity of variances.